# How to test whether a function was waited on, not only called?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Consider testing the following simplified function

```
const functionToBeTested = async (val) => {
    await otherModule.otherFunction(val/2);
}
```

In my jest test I want to make sure that the `otherModule.otherFunction` is not only called but also waited on. In other words, I want to write a test that will fail if someone removes the `await` from in front of the `otherFunction` call.

I have so far this

```
test('should wait on otherFunction', () => {
   await functionToBeTested(6) 
   expect(otherModule.otherFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);  
}
```

But the `expect(otherModule.otherFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);`  check does not verify that `functionToBeTested` has waited on `otherFunction`.

Comment: Can you check the first value to be not what it should be when the second function gets called and then check it again after the second function gets called

Comment: simply don't test whether it's finished or not, it's implement detail, or you have a concrete use case?

Comment: [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55057124/10149510) for `Mocha` and `Sinon`...the same concepts apply to using `Jest`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i came up with:

```
const delay = duration => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));

test('should wait on otherFunction', async () => {
  let resolve;
  const mockPromise = new Promise((res) => {resolve = res;});
  otherModule.otherFunction.mockReturnValue(mockPromise);
  const resolution = jest.fn();

  functionToBeTested(6).then(resolution);

  expect(otherModule.otherFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
  await delay(0);
  expect(resolution).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  resolve();
  await delay(0);
  expect(resolution).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

So, i mock otherFunction to return a promise which starts unresolved, but i can resolve it at will during the test. Then i call the function i want to test, and give it a callback for when its complete.

I then want to assert that it did not call the callback, but since promise resolution is always asynchronous i need to add in a timeout 0 to give the promise a chance to resolve. I chose to do this with a promis-ified version of setTimeout.

And finally, i resolve the mockPromise, do a timeout 0 (again, to make sure the promise gets a chance to call its callbacks), and assert that now the resolution *has* been called.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot check against `otherModule.otherFunction` resolved value or on any side-effects, there is no need to test wether it resolves.

Otherwise, removing `await` in following examples will cause the tests to fail.

```
describe('check for side effect', () => {
    let sideEffect = false;

    const otherModule = {
        otherFunction: x =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    sideEffect = true;
                    resolve();
                }, 0);
            }),
    };

    const functionToBeTested = async val => {
        await otherModule.otherFunction(val / 2);
    };

    test('should wait on otherFunction', async () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(otherModule, 'otherFunction');

        await expect(functionToBeTested(6)).resolves.toBeUndefined();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
        expect(sideEffect).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

```
describe('check returned value', () => {
    const otherModule = {
        otherFunction: x =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve('hello');
                }, 0);
            }),
    };

    const functionToBeTested = async val => {
        const res = await otherModule.otherFunction(val / 2);
        return `*** ${res} ***`;
    };

    test('should wait on otherFunction', async () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(otherModule, 'otherFunction');

        const promise = functionToBeTested(6);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
        await expect(promise).resolves.toBe('*** hello ***');
    });
});
```